# Open application link in background without

Tags: javascript, html, spotify

I am trying to make a song start playing in spotify from the browser, I have it working somewhat right now by using `window.location.assign`, but the issue is that it makes the spotify app open and cover the browser, which I do not want.

Is there anyway to `execute` a link without causing the programs window to open?

Current example here
http://jsfiddle.net/5meyH/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the command is not window.location.assign, it is just window.location(param).

This not what you are looking for, however. Unfortunately, the only ways you could do this are to embed it (if Spotify supports that) or to retrieve some sort of feed from the site, which Spotify must also support. The reason is that when you go to that URL, it has lots of information from the browser: HTML to present, CSS to change the looks, JS to make it interactive, etc. By requesting a link you are asking for all of those elements, not just sound.

To sum up: no, unless Spotify supports a feed or embeds.

Comment: is there a way that I cam use something like window.focus() to instantly bring the window back to the front right after executing the function to open the link?

Comment: You got it, window.focus() is right. But if you are going to make an entirely new window, you want to say 'window.open(URL)' instead of .location().